# No transition in angular ui bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've re-used the angular-based carousel here:
http://codepen.io/hamzaisaac/pen/avaVYK

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
    <div style="height: 305px">
      <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
        <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
          <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
            <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
          </div>
        </uib-slide>
      </uib-carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 1000 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: '//placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
        ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
    });
  };
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }
});
```

It works, but I can't achieve the same transition effect in the original code: 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#carousel

Why? I've included all of the dependencies including Angularjs and UI Bootstrap.
Is there anything that I've missed here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing the ng-animate dependency.

`angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])`

If you are using bower then simply install the dependency using

`bower install angular-animate`

OR using npm

`npm install angular-animate`

and including the js in your `index.html`

`<script src="/path/to/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>`